# problem iterating on an empty dictionary Delphi 10.4

Tags: dictionary, delphi, iteration

I have the following code with two dictionaries. I can see that when I iterate through DictForbidden even though it is empty the execution flow enters the loop so DictToAdd.remove(anInteger); is executed with
the old value of anInteger

```
var DictForbidden, DictToAdd : TDictionary<Integer,boolean>; 
var anInteger: Integer;
    
DictForbidden   := TDictionary<Integer,boolean>.Create;
DictToAdd       := TDictionary<Integer,boolean>.Create;
    
anInteger := 1;
DictToAdd.Add(anInteger,true);
    
for anInteger in DictForbidden.Keys do
  DictToAdd.remove(anInteger);
    
DictForbidden.Free;
DictToAdd.Free;
```

I am running Delphi 10.4 and I don't recall such a behavior in 10.3. I think back then if the dictionary was empty the loop was not entered. Do you know if this is something new on Delphi 10.4?, or maybe I am doing something wrong here?

regards, Carlos

Comment: You are not doing anything wrong, and this works as expected on my 10.3. Don't have access to 10.4 at the moment.

Comment: Are you absolutely sure that `Remove` is actually called? What happens if you put `ShowMessage(DictToAdd.Count.ToString)` after the loop, before the cleanup?

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand: It'll probably report 1 in any case, as there's no guarantee (even if it loops once) that it will remove the value 1 - it might (if there's a bug in the compiler) loop once with anInteger at any random value. Better to include a "visible" statement inside the loop to see if the inner part of the loop is being executed at all...

Comment: @HeartWare: Correct, my bad.

Comment: Remove an item while iterating in the list brings unfortunately some troubles with the iterator. I recommend using a reverse for-loop so you iterate with for-down-to or write a while loop.

Comment: @SchneiderInfosystemsLtd: Notice that the FOR-IN loop iterates `DictForbidden` but removes from `DictToAdd`.

Comment: @HeartWare: I have overlooked this point. Yes in that case my input here is not the cause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my 10.4.1 it doesn't enter the loop. But it may look like it does when you debug trace due to optimization made by the compiler. Try replacing the

```
DictToAdd.Remove
```

with a

```
writeln(anInteger) // if Console Application
ShowMessage(IntToStr(anInteger)) // if GUI Application
```

and see if anything is reported.

Answer (score 0):

thank you very much for the quick help!

Actually you are right @Heartware. After the loop, DictToAdd still contains a 1. So basically there is no case here rather than putting a break point in the line DictToAdd.remove(anInteger); the execution is stopped and putting then the cursor above anInteger you see the value is 1 but stepping over the 1 is not being removed. When replacing the removal by a showmessage I observe the same thing the break point is reached but the showmessage is not executed.

Also noticed that when using a begin/end like this

```
for anInteger in DictForbidden.Keys do
begin
  DictToAdd.remove(anInteger);
end;
```

the break point is not reached.

Comment: Remember to accept the answer that replied to your question and/or upvote answers that you think is useful.

Answer (score 0):

This is a little annoyance with the debugger caused by the fact that a loop of course produces some executable code - especially a for in loop that has calls to `MoveNext` and `Current` and some cleanup code for the enumerator after it completes.

This code has to go somewhere and often the line information being used by the debugger (aka "the blue dots") of that code overlap with actual code you wrote like in this case.

To illustrate this here is how the disassembly looks like when I put your code into a console application.

[image]

As you can see there are two breakpoints displayed here which belong to the same one breakpoint I placed in line 21. But the one that got hit is the one with the cleanup code which is responsible for destroying the enumerator. If you hit F7 and you compiled with debug dcus you will notice that it actually does not go into `TDictionary.Remove` but into `TObject.Destroy`.

Now the disassembly after placing the `begin` and `end`:

[image]

Again two breakpoints shown but this time I actually placed them both myself - and they are for different lines.